# 'Invalid object ID' error remove document

Tags: php, mongodb

```
 echo "Enter Id which you want to delete\n";
 $id= fgets(STDIN);

// settype($id, "string");

 $c->remove(array("_id"=> new MongoId($id)));
```

i just want to remove the document by getting id" as input from user.

But i am getting error shown below-
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'Invalid object ID'

Comment: you are not entering proper $id

Comment: no,i am using mongo id as id like 5846717f71243d42a2b0e94d

Comment: if i am giving directly $id=5846717f71243d42a2b0e94d;

Comment: then it is working

Comment: exactly my point. the error is probably in your input

Comment: You stored `_id` in your DB as a String not a MongoId(ObjectId)! therefore remove that `new MongoId()` or fix your data in your monog (which i would recommend more!)

Comment: this is my one document

Array
(
    [Cell] => 123456
    [Location] => Hyderabad
    [Name] => Ravi
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 5846717f71243d42a2b0e94d
        )